# Where to store global variables in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

Noob question.

Writing a GUI in Visual Basic and I want global variables (specifically an array of objects that will should be initialized every time)

Do I put this in my module? I understand this is where global variables are supposed to go.

atm I have declared the array but I cannot initialize it outside of a method. I understand that I have to put it in a method but how should I make this method that should be run automatically? If I use the properties menu and make the program run from a Sub Main then I'm not sure how I would get the GUI to load.

Thanks

Hopefully that was clear, please ask me to rephrase if it's not.

Comment: Project + Properties, Application tab, "View Application Events" button.  Add the MyApplication_Startup event.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Just had to double click my main form and it generated a load event/trigger.